# How do you figure out gstreamer profile strings

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch, gst-launch-1.0

Trying to use encodebin and its profiles. The documentations here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pbutils/encoding-profile.html?gi-language=c#defining-a-gstencodingprofile-as-a-string and there: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/1.9/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-encoding-profile.html#GstEncodingProfile list examples, but they don't really explain how I actually construct those strings.

It names the generic `muxer_source_caps:video_encoder_source_caps:audio_encoder_source_caps` format, but where do I get muxer_source_caps from. `application/ogg:audio/x-vorbis` from the examples works totally fine.

For instance, how would I proceed to figure out the needed profile to encode to aac in an mp4 container.

Making wild guesses to use mime types from https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/cc55b304ef4ab1cd95f6348d33f268ccebaab8e8/docs/random/mimetypes also won't work.

all attempts are failing with `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "profile" in element "enc"` or some longer errors when only using `audio/x-m4a` without a muxer_source_cap

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least for ogg, though it doesn't work that way for the other formats I tried.

by using `gst-inspect-1.0 | grep ogg -i` oggmux can be found

`gst-inspect-1.0 oggmux` yields, among other things:

```
  SINK template: 'audio_%u'
    Availability: On request
    Capabilities:
      audio/x-vorbis

  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      application/ogg
```

muxer_source_caps is `SRC template`, which is `application/ogg`

audio_encoder_source_caps is `SINK template`, which is `audio/x-vorbis`

makes `application/ogg:audio/x-vorbis`

sometimes there are variables, like `layer` in xingmux. Those are added like:

`audio/mpeg,mpegversion=1,layer=3`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272399 on how encodebin is used in a pipeline